# npm mongoose installation in Windows machine local repository not working

Tags: mongoose, npm, npm-install, mlab

I'm trying to install mongoose to my local repository `(c:\Users\kelumputha\Desktop\userstory)` using following command in windows powershell

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

Also I'm using mongo db in Database-as-a-Service by mLab, So I have a `config.js` file as

```
module.exports = {

    "database": "mongodb://kelum:****@ds111188.mlab.com:11188/userstorydb",
    "port": process.env.PORT || 3000,
    "secretKey": "YourSecretKey"
}
```

but here I'm ending with

> No Repository Field

Warning

[image]

Comment: This is just a npm warning, check your `../userstory/node_modules` folder and make sure `mongoose` folder is created, then you're good to go!

Comment: @BasimHennawi yes its there

Comment: It should be working then. Would you try require and use `mongoose` in your code/app?

Comment: @BasimHennawi yes [this is how](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/997eE) I do it currently,  then I'm trying to run the demon using `nodemon server` but ending with this error http://i.imgur.com/fIFO8h5.png

Comment: So the error isn't related to `mongoose` now but `nodemon`, maybe you want to install it properly in your local mchine `npm install nodemon -g` and add it to environment path.

Comment: Actually I'm new to this technology, yes I thought that one related with npm mongoose installation , so I install using this command `$  npm install -g nodemon` now everything seems fine, kudos for the support :)

Comment: Anytime, good luck with your project!